# Bayesian Gaussian Mixture model

Tags: bayesian, mean, python, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I am trying to fit basic Gaussian mixture with a Bayesian model.

My likelihood function is Gaussian, with std=1, and the only parameter is the mean, chosen from $\{0,1,\dots,14,15\}$ and my prior is uniform.

I would expect that if the data is sampled from 2 distinct Gaussians, then the posterior distribution should converge to those two Gaussian means.

Where in fact, the Bayesian model converged to one Gaussian model with **the mean of the two means** of the two Gaussians.

Here is my code:

```
import bayes
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
mixture_means=[5,10]
sample_size=30
mixture=list(np.random.normal(mixture_means[0],size=sample_size/2))+list(np.random.normal(mixture_means[1],size=sample_size/2))
model=bayes.DiscreteBayes()
vals=range(16)
def norm_likelihood(mean,std=1.0):
    '''Returns normal likelihood function with given mean and std'''
    ret=map(norm.pdf,[(v-mean)/std for v in vals])
    s=sum(ret)
    ret=map(lambda x:x/s,ret)
    return lambda i: ret[int(round(i))] if int(round(i)) in vals else 0

for v in vals:
    model.hypo[v]=bayes.hypothesis(likelihood=norm_likelihood(v),belief=1.0)
model.normalize()
model.update(mixture)
posterior=[m.belief for m in model.hypo.values()]
```

The content of the bayes module can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411707/bayesian-statistics)

The resulting posterior distribution is

```
{0: 0.0,
 1: 1.7310930899121284e-247,
 2: 2.1969933450785758e-174,
 3: 1.2166851528859524e-113,
 4: 7.1750915476302883e-66,
 5: 3.9752699764577839e-31,
 6: 2.0610600467738752e-09,
 7: 0.99995460007033121,
 8: 4.5397868608866683e-05,
 9: 1.9286622833850024e-22,
 10: 7.6673013627085034e-53,
 11: 2.8524215798147219e-96,
 12: 9.9695335021693221e-153,
 13: 3.7105281612774415e-222,
 14: 0.0,
 15: 0.0}
```

Where the actual 2 means are $5$ and $10$, and for some reason the posterior converged to $7$.

### Why is that ?

The belief for gaussian $\mu=5$ and $\mu=10$ should be strongest, since the data is actually being sampled from those distribution.

Instead, we see that the belief for those two means is negligible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to fit a single normal $\mathcal{N}(\theta,1)$ model to your sample, which means that the posterior will concentrate on the largest [in $\theta$] values of
\begin{align*}\prod_{i=1}^n \exp\{-(x_i-\theta)^2/2\}
&=\exp\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\theta)^2/2\right\}\\
&=\exp\left\{ -\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x}_n)^2/2-n(\bar{x}_n-\theta)^2/2\right\}\\
&\propto\exp\left\{-n(\bar{x}_n-\theta)^2/2\right\}\end{align*}
Due to the normal modelling, all that matters is the data average, $\bar{x}_n$, since the posterior is
$$\theta|x_1,\ldots,x_n\sim \mathcal{N}(\bar{x}_n,1/n),$$
so it is natural that the largest posterior weights are around $7$ and $8$. That $7$ gets most of the weight is a reflection of the sample, another round would put more weight on $8$.

In other words, there is no information in the normal model that the data is from a mixture, hence no reason to identify two means.